# C++11 multithreaded cancellable slice-based work

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I am trying to create a base class to manage a slice-based workload.
My approach was to create a base abstract class that handles the initialization/termination of the work and inherit from that class in specific classes that only specify the actual work and timings.
I also added the functionality in the base class to reinitialize the workload if a set number of errors occur.

This works as expected in a simple example (given below) and with most workloads that I have but when I try to use this with a specific workload (reading a serial port that's written to by an arduino) it completely messes up the stream read from arduino.
I suspect there is some problem with my approach but I couldn't figure it out...

Here is my code:

**sliceWork.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <future>
using namespace ::std;

class sliceWork
{
    int sliceIntervalMilliSeconds;
    int failureCounter;
    int maxFailsBeforeRestart;
    char* label = NULL;
    
    promise<void> workPromise;
    thread* workerThread = NULL;

    virtual void init() = 0;
    virtual bool oneSliceWork() = 0;
    void work(future<void> future);

public:
    sliceWork(int sliceInterval, int maxFails, const char* label);
    ~sliceWork();
    void initWork();
    void signalTerminate();
};
```

**sliceWork.cpp**

```
#include <string.h>
#include "sliceWork.h"

sliceWork::sliceWork(int interval, int maxFails, const char* workLabel)
{
    sliceIntervalMilliSeconds = interval;
    maxFailsBeforeRestart = maxFails;
    label = new char[strlen(workLabel) + 1];
    strcpy(label, workLabel);
}

sliceWork::~sliceWork()
{
    if (workerThread != NULL && workerThread->joinable())
        workerThread->join();
    printf("destructor %s\n", label);
    delete label;
    delete workerThread;
}

void sliceWork::initWork()
{
    failureCounter = 0;
    init();
    printf("Init work %s finished!\n", label);
    future<void> futureWorker = workPromise.get_future();
    workerThread = new thread(&sliceWork::work, this, move(futureWorker));
}

void sliceWork::work(future<void> future)
{
    using namespace ::std::chrono;
    steady_clock::time_point t0 = steady_clock::now();

    while (future.wait_for(chrono::milliseconds(1)) == future_status::timeout)
    {
        if (duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(steady_clock::now() - t0).count() 
            > sliceIntervalMilliSeconds)
        {
            if (!oneSliceWork())
            {
                if (++failureCounter > maxFailsBeforeRestart 
                    && maxFailsBeforeRestart > 0)
                {
                    init();
                    failureCounter = 0;
                }
            }
            t0 = steady_clock::now();
        }
    }
    printf("work terminated for %s!\n", label);
}

void sliceWork::signalTerminate()
{
    printf("request terminate for work %s...\n", label);
    workPromise.set_value();
}
```

And here is an example of using it that works as expected:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <string.h>
#include "sliceWork.h"

class A : public sliceWork
{
    void init() {
        printf("Init A...\n");
    }

    bool oneSliceWork() {
        printf("Working A...\n");
        return true;
    }
public:
    A(int slice, int max, const char* label) 
        : sliceWork(slice, max, label) 
    {
    }
};

class B : public sliceWork
{
    void init() {
        printf("Init B...\n");
    }

    bool oneSliceWork() {
        printf("Working B...\n");
        return true;
    }
public:
    B(int slice, int max, const char* label) 
        : sliceWork(slice, max, label) 
    {
    }
};

class C : public sliceWork
{
    void init() {
        printf("Init C...\n");
    }

    bool oneSliceWork() {
        printf("Working C...\n");
        return false;
    }
public:
    C(int slice, int max, const char* label) 
        : sliceWork(slice, max, label) 
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
     {
         A a(1000, 1000, "A");
         a.initWork();
         B b(2000, 1000, "B" );
         b.initWork();
         C c(700, 2, "C" );
         c.initWork();
         printf("Initializations finished!\n");
         ::std::this_thread::sleep_for(::std::chrono::seconds(7));
         a.signalTerminate();
         ::std::this_thread::sleep_for(::std::chrono::seconds(5));
         b.signalTerminate();
         ::std::this_thread::sleep_for(::std::chrono::seconds(4));
         c.signalTerminate();
     }
     getchar();
     return 0;
}
```

So, I want to ask if this approach is prone to error because the way I implemented the functionality.

Application is written in C++11 and targets an Raspberry PI 3b+ running the Raspberry's flavor of Debian 11 (Raspbian), if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++11 we use keyword `nullptr` instead of `NULL` macro. Moreover, `std::thread` is movable, so it is much better to use it as value rather than pointer:

```
class sliceWork{
    ///...
    std::thread workerThread;
    ///...
    ~sliceWork(){
        ///...
        if (workerThread.joinable())
            workerThread.join();
        ///...
    };
    ///...
    void initWork(){
        ///...
        workerThread = thread{[this](){
            work(workPromise.get_future());
        }};
        ///...
    };
};
```

I used a lambda to initialize the thread instead of your original code; it has better minimally performance, while more readable IMO.

If you can use C++17, then I strongly recommend using `std::string_view` over old null-terminated strings; otherwise just use `std::string`. Also using constructor member initializer list is always recommended:

```
#include <string>
class sliceWork{
    ///...
    std::string_view label;
    ///...
    sliceWork(int interval, int maxFails, std::string_view workLabel):
        sliceIntervalMilliSeconds {interval},
        maxFailsBeforeRestart {maxFails},
        label {workLabel}
    {};
    ///...
};
```

If you can use C++20 however, `std::jthread` is of huge advantages over `std::thread`. Because now that you already don't `delete` the `label` or `workerThread` and the destructor of `std::jthread` automatically joins, you can totally drop the destructor of `sliceWork`; the `default` compiler-provided destructor will do!! Plus, you can even get rid of the `workPromise`:

```
class sliceWork{
    ///...
    std::string_view label;
    ///...
    std::jthread workerThread;
    ///...
    //std::promise<void> workPromise;//we don't need this
    ///...
    //~sliceWork()=default;
    ///...
    void signalTerminate(){
    ///...
        workerThread.request_stop();
    }
    ///...
    void initWork(){
        ///...
        workerThread = jthread{[this](std::stop_token stop_token){
            work(std::move(stop_token));
        }};
        ///...
    };
    ///...
    void work(std::stop_token stoken){
        ///...
        for(int ticks{0}; !stoken.stop_requested(); sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1)), ++ticks) {
        if (ticks > sliceIntervalMilliSeconds) {
                ///...
            }; //if
            ///...
        }; //for
        ///...
    };//work
};
```

One final word: almost never use `printf`; it has lots of caveats. In C++ we use `std::cout`. In multi_threaded applications, end the `std::cout` instructions with  `<< std::endl`; this flushes the buffer and helps the output to be more readable.

Comment: Thank you Red.Wave for your detailed answer! I need to stick with C++11 though because down the road I would like to have the option to port the code to an esp32.

Comment: . I've been away from micro for a while. But back then, major IDEs used to have good C++ support. I believe C++ is better than C specially on micro.